# Using cron in Meteor to send emails in the future

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, cron

I am using [`percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron`](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) to try and send email reminders that an invoice is due. For example, if I send an invoice and select "due in 7 days", i want the recipient of my invoice to get an email 7 days from now saying that the invoice is due.

createInvoice.js (client)

```
Template.createTransfer.events({
  'submit form': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var transfer = {
      userId: Meteor.userId(),
      date: Date(),
      files: Session.get('files'),
      senderEmail: template.find('#senderEmail').value,
      recipientEmail: template.find('#recipientEmail').value,
      message: template.find('#message').value
    };

    if (Session.get('invoice')) {
      transfer.invoice = {
        total: template.find('#total').value,
        due: template.find('#due').value,
        stripe: Meteor.user().services.stripe
      };
    }

    Transfers.insert(transfer, function (error, id) {
      if (error) {
        showError(error);
      } else {
        Session.set('files');
        showAlert('Transfers sent!');
        transfer._id = id;
        Meteor.call('sendEmail', transfer);
        Router.go('viewTransfer', {_id: id});
      }
    });
    scheduleEmail(transfer);

  }
});

function scheduleEmail(transfer) {

  if (transfer.date < moment(new Date())) {
    Meteor.call('sendMail', transfer);
  } else {
    if (transfer.invoice.due == "7 days") {
      if (moment(transfer.date).add(7, 'days').calendar() == moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) {
        var thisId = FutureEmails.insert(transfer);
        Meteor.call('addCronMail',thisId, transfer);
      }
    } else if (transfer.invoice.due == "14 days") {
      if (moment(transfer.date).add(14, 'days').calendar() == moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) {
        var thisId = FutureEmails.insert(transfer);
        Meteor.call('addCronMail',thisId, transfer);
      }
    } else if (transfer.invoice.due == "30 days") {
      if (moment(transfer.date).add(30, 'days').calendar() == moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) {
        var thisId = FutureEmails.insert(transfer);
        Meteor.call('addCronMail',thisId, transfer);
      }
    } else if (transfer.invoice.due == "90 days") {
      if (moment(transfer.date).add(90, 'days').calendar() == moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY")) {
        var thisId = FutureEmails.insert(transfer);
        Meteor.call('addCronMail',thisId, transfer);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

methods.js (server)

```
Meteor.methods({

  //other methods

  sendMail: function(transfer) {

    check([transfer.senderEmail,
      transfer.recipientEmail,
      transfer.message,
      // transfer.invoice.total
      ], [String]);

      // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
      // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
      this.unblock();

      transfer.url = Meteor.absoluteUrl() +'transfer/' + transfer._id;

      var template = 'invoice-due';

      Email.send({
        to: transfer.recipientEmail,
        bcc: transfer.senderEmail,
        from: transfer.senderEmail,
        subject: transfer.senderEmail + ' sent you files!',
        html: Handlebars.templates[template](transfer)
      });

    },

    addCronMail: function(id, transfer) {

      SyncedCron.add({
        name: id,
        schedule: function(parser) {
          // return parser.recur().on(transfer.date).fullDate();
          return parser.recur().every(3).minute();
        },
        job: function() {
          Meteor.call('sendMail',transfer);
          FutureEmails.remove(id);
          SyncedCron.remove(id);
          return id;
        }
      });

    }
});
```

and startup.js(server)

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  FutureEmails.find().forEach(function(mail) {
    if (moment(mail.date).format("MMM Do YY") < moment(new Date()).format("MMM Do YY")) {
      Meteor.call('sendMail', mail);
    } else {
      Meteor.call('addCronMail', mail._id, mail);
    }
  });
  SyncedCron.start();
});
```

I know im checking for the different due dates in the wrong place. Where do I perform the check to see if it's been 7, 14, etc days and if it has, send out the email?